# Function for comparison operator in R

Tags: r, function, comparison, operator-keyword

I would like to define an R function in which I can select a comparison operator, like

```
fun <- function(x,y, op){
  if (op = "<"){
     comp_fun = <function for less than>
  } else if (op = "<="){
     comp_fun = <function for less equal than>
  }

return(comp_fun(x,y))
}
```

This is just a toy example, but I would like to know which function implement the four "<", "<=", ">" and ">=" operators.

Comment: Why not define four functions outside of `fun` and then call one of them based on your if conditions?

Comment: it is not very elegant, it leads to a lot of code duplication...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Operators are functions already, so you don't need an extra layer.

```
x <- 1:5
y <- 5:1
`<`(x, y)
## [1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
"<"(x, y)
## [1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Though as James and Roland mentioned, you can use `get` or `match.fun`.

```
op <- "<"
get(op)(x, y)
## [1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
match.fun(op)(x, y)
## [1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Though be warned that using the `op` variable directly doesn't work

```
op(x, y)
## Error: could not find function "op"
```

Comment: me neither, that's exactly what I wanted :)

Comment: @Roland, @LucaCerone You can do it with if and for, etc. as well.  Try `\`if\`(TRUE, message("We're using if as a function!"))` or `\`for\`(i, 1:5, print(i))`

Comment: @RichieCotton I new that you can do it with backticks. I just didn't know that it is also possible with quotation marks.

Comment: actually it doesn't work..
if I do fun = "<" then I can't apply fun(3,4)

Answer (score 2):

You could use `get` and keep in mind that logical operators are actually functions:

```
fun <- function(x,y, op){
  get(op)(x,y)
}

fun(4,3,">=")
#[1] TRUE
fun(4,3,"<")
#[1] FALSE
```

**Edit:**

You could also use `match.fun`, which was designed for this and adds some checks.

```
fun <- function(x,y, op){
  match.fun(op)(x,y)
}
```

Comment: I think `match.fun` might be safer than `get`

Comment: @James Well, it adds some checks. From `help("match.fun")`: If FUN is a function, it is returned. If it is a symbol (for example, enclosed in backquotes) or a character vector of length one, it will be looked up using get in the environment of the parent of the caller.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you want it, but you can do it like this:

```
fun <- function(x,y, op){
   return(eval(parse(text=paste(x,op,y))))
}

fun(4,3,">=") # example, returns TRUE
```

Obviously if you want more complicated function calls, you need to add conditions in the function, but for comparison operators of 2 variables this should be the quickest [if you REALLY REALLY have to do it this way]

Comment: `Personally I have never regretted trying not to underestimate my own future stupidity.
   -- Greg Snow (explaining why eval(parse(...)) is often suboptimal, answering a question triggered
      by the infamous fortune(106))
      R-help (January 2007)`

Comment: It's got its place. Although also not sure if this is that place ;)