# How to pass comparison operator into a function as an argument?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am creating a number of visualizations that highlight data that fail to meet some pre-specified threshold.

Minimal code is:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)
library(ggrepel)

set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(record_id = paste0('par', seq(1:100)),
                 var = sample(1:100))

plot_fn <- function(yvar, threshold){
  yvar <- eval(substitute(yvar), df)
  df %>% ggplot(aes(x=factor(0), y = get(yvar))) +
  geom_jitter() +
  geom_hline(yintercept = threshold) +
  geom_label_repel(data = subset(df, get(yvar) >= threshold), aes(label = record_id))
}

plot_fn('var', 95)
```

I am wondering how I can additional pass a comparison operator (e.g., '>=', '<') into the function for use by geom_label_repel. I have tried to implement the suggestions in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20142440/function-for-comparison-operator-in-r), namely using `get` and `match.fun`, but to no avail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can pass the operator as an additional argument and capture it with `match.fun`

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggrepel)

plot_fn <- function(yvar, threshold, operat){

   fun1 <- match.fun(operat)
   df %>% ggplot(aes(x=factor(0), y = get(yvar))) +
    geom_jitter() +
    geom_hline(yintercept = threshold) +
    geom_label_repel(data = subset(df, fun1(get(yvar), threshold)), 
                     aes(label = record_id))
}

plot_fn('var', 95, ">=")
```

[image]

```
plot_fn('var', 95, "==")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I was using `match.fun` improperly; this is exactly what I had hoped to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

We can make use the `{{}}` and pass column name as unquoted

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggrepel)
plot_fn <- function(df, yvar, threshold){

        df %>% 
              ggplot(aes(x=factor(0), y = {{yvar}})) +
                 geom_jitter() +
               geom_hline(yintercept = threshold) +
                geom_label_repel(data = df %>% 
                    filter({{yvar}} >= threshold), 
                      aes(label = record_id))
      }


plot_fn(df, var, 95)
```

[image]

---

If we want to pass the `>=` as a string into the function as parameter

```
plot_fn <- function(df, yvar, threshold, param){

           subdf <- df %>% 
                 filter(!! rlang::parse_expr(str_c(rlang::ensym(yvar),
               param,  threshold, sep=" ")))
                  df %>% 
                        ggplot(aes(x=factor(0), y = {{yvar}})) +
                           geom_jitter() +
                         geom_hline(yintercept = threshold) +
                          geom_label_repel(data = subdf , 
                                aes(label = record_id))
                }

plot_fn(df, var, 95, ">=")
```

[image]

```
 plot_fn(df, var, 95, "==")
```

[image]

Comment: This is very nice, I will definitely make use of that, thank you. However, here I am hoping to pass a comparison operator as an argument to the function (in my example, to replace the `>=` in the call to geom_label_repel). Do you know how I might do that?

Comment: @navoan Are you passing a parameter `">="` string into the function?

Comment: Yes, I have tried to. However, if I provide anything other than the comparison operator proper to geom_label_repel, I am getting an "unexpected symbol" error.